# Objective C DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, des

im trying to implement an encryption way on iOS . to match the one running on JAVA .

but every thing i tried result in a different encrypted schema

here is my Java Code that i Use for Encryption :

```
  public static String encrypt(String plaintext)
    throws Exception
  {
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(sharedkey, "DESede"), new IvParameterSpec(sharedvector));
    byte[] encrypted = c.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    return Base64.encode(encrypted);
  }
```

is there any easy way to use DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding in objective c ?

this is the code I'm Using but it gives different result

```
+ (NSString*) doCipher:(NSString*)plainText:(CCOperation)encryptOrDecrypt {

    const void *vplainText;
    size_t plainTextBufferSize;

    if (encryptOrDecrypt == kCCDecrypt)
    {
       // NSData *EncryptData = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:plainText];
       // plainTextBufferSize = [EncryptData length];
       // vplainText = [EncryptData bytes];
    }
    else
    {
        NSData *tempData = [plainText dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        plainTextBufferSize = [tempData length];
        vplainText =  [tempData bytes];
    }

    CCCryptorStatus ccStatus;
    uint8_t *bufferPtr = NULL;
    size_t bufferPtrSize = 0;
    size_t movedBytes = 0;
    //  uint8_t ivkCCBlockSize3DES;

    bufferPtrSize = (plainTextBufferSize + kCCBlockSize3DES) & ~(kCCBlockSize3DES - 1);
    bufferPtr = malloc( bufferPtrSize * sizeof(uint8_t));
    memset((void *)bufferPtr, 0x0, bufferPtrSize);


    //my shared key i changed to Zeros 
    NSMutableData *payload = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        [payload appendBytes:"00" length:1];
        [payload appendBytes:"00" length:1];
        [payload appendBytes:"00" length:1];
        [payload appendBytes:"00" length:1];
        [payload appendBytes:"00" length:1];
        [payload appendBytes:"00" length:1];
        [payload appendBytes:"00" length:1];
        [payload appendBytes:"00" length:1];
        [payload appendBytes:"00" length:1];
        [payload appendBytes:"00" length:1];
        [payload appendBytes:"00" length:1];
        [payload appendBytes:"00" length:1];
        [payload appendBytes:"00" length:1];
     [payload appendBytes:"00" length:1];
    [payload appendBytes:"00" length:1];
    [payload appendBytes:"00" length:1];
    [payload appendBytes:"00" length:1];
    [payload appendBytes:"00" length:1];
    [payload appendBytes:"00" length:1];
    [payload appendBytes:"00" length:1];
    [payload appendBytes:"00" length:1];
    [payload appendBytes:"00" length:1];
    [payload appendBytes:"00" length:1];
    [payload appendBytes:"00" length:1];

    NSString *key = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:payload encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//my iV i changed it to zeros 
    NSMutableData *IV = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    [IV appendBytes:"00" length:1];
    [IV appendBytes:"00" length:1];
    [IV appendBytes:"00" length:1];
    [IV appendBytes:"00" length:1];
    [IV appendBytes:"00" length:1];
    [IV appendBytes:"00" length:1];
    [IV appendBytes:"00" length:1];
    [IV appendBytes:"00" length:1];

    NSLog(@"key byte is %s", [payload bytes]);
     NSLog(@"IV byte is %s", [IV bytes]);
    // Initialization vector; dummy in this case 0's.
    uint8_t iv[kCCBlockSize3DES];
    memset((void *) iv, 0x0, (size_t) sizeof(iv));

    ccStatus = CCCrypt(encryptOrDecrypt,
                       kCCAlgorithm3DES,
                       kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                       (const void *)[payload bytes], //"123456789012345678901234", //key
                       kCCKeySize3DES,
                       [IV bytes],  //iv,
                       vplainText,  //plainText,
                       plainTextBufferSize,
                       (void *)bufferPtr,
                       bufferPtrSize,
                       &movedBytes);

    //if (ccStatus == kCCSuccess) NSLog(@"SUCCESS");
    /*else*/ if (ccStatus == kCCParamError) return @"PARAM ERROR";
    else if (ccStatus == kCCBufferTooSmall) return @"BUFFER TOO SMALL";
    else if (ccStatus == kCCMemoryFailure) return @"MEMORY FAILURE";
    else if (ccStatus == kCCAlignmentError) return @"ALIGNMENT";
    else if (ccStatus == kCCDecodeError) return @"DECODE ERROR";
    else if (ccStatus == kCCUnimplemented) return @"UNIMPLEMENTED";

    NSString *result;

    if (encryptOrDecrypt == kCCDecrypt)
    {

        //  result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bufferPtr length:[(NSUInteger)movedBytes] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
        result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bufferPtr length:(NSUInteger)movedBytes] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    }
    else
    {
        NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bufferPtr length:(NSUInteger)movedBytes];
        NSLog(@"data is: %@", myData);
        result = [myData base64EncodedString];
      //  result = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that the key data is correct on both sides? You need to check the value encoded as *bytes*, possibly it is best to verify all values using hexadecimals at both sides. The algorithm seems to match, so that's likely correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@owlstead thanx for your hint ,

i really checked every thing and you are right the problem was with the input

so here is the right way to enter the input :

```
  unsigned char result1[24]=      {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,00,00,00,00,0};
    unsigned char IV3[8]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

off-course you have to change the numbers to your own key and IV .

the Full Code : just change the IV and the result to your data :)

```
    - (NSString*) doCipher:(NSString*)plainText enc:(CCOperation)encryptOrDecrypt{

    const void *vplainText;
    size_t plainTextBufferSize;





    if (encryptOrDecrypt == kCCDecrypt)
    {
        NSData *EncryptData =[NSData  dataWithBase64EncodedString:plainText];
        plainTextBufferSize = [EncryptData length];
        vplainText = [EncryptData bytes];
    }
    else
    {
        plainTextBufferSize = [plainText length];
        vplainText = (const void *) [plainText UTF8String];
    }


    CCCryptorStatus ccStatus;
    uint8_t *bufferPtr = NULL;
    size_t bufferPtrSize = 0;
    size_t movedBytes = 0;
    //  uint8_t ivkCCBlockSize3DES;

    bufferPtrSize = (plainTextBufferSize + kCCBlockSize3DES) & ~(kCCBlockSize3DES - 1);
    bufferPtr = malloc( bufferPtrSize * sizeof(uint8_t));
    memset((void *)bufferPtr, 0x0, bufferPtrSize);


    unsigned char result1[24]= {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,00,00,00,00,0};
    unsigned char IV3[8]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    uint8_t iv[kCCBlockSize3DES];
    memset((void *) iv, 0x0, (size_t) sizeof(iv));

    ccStatus = CCCrypt(encryptOrDecrypt,
                       kCCAlgorithm3DES,
                       kCCOptionPKCS7Padding ,
                       result1, //"123456789012345678901234", //key
                       kCCKeySize3DES,
                       IV3 ,  //iv,
                       vplainText,  //plainText,
                       plainTextBufferSize,
                       (void *)bufferPtr,
                       bufferPtrSize,
                       &movedBytes);

    //if (ccStatus == kCCSuccess) NSLog(@"SUCCESS");
    /*else*/ if (ccStatus == kCCParamError) return @"PARAM ERROR";
    else if (ccStatus == kCCBufferTooSmall) return @"BUFFER TOO SMALL";
    else if (ccStatus == kCCMemoryFailure) return @"MEMORY FAILURE";
    else if (ccStatus == kCCAlignmentError) return @"ALIGNMENT";
    else if (ccStatus == kCCDecodeError) return @"DECODE ERROR";
    else if (ccStatus == kCCUnimplemented) return @"UNIMPLEMENTED";

    NSString *result;

    if (encryptOrDecrypt == kCCDecrypt)
    {


        result = [ [NSString alloc] initWithData: [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bufferPtr length:(NSUInteger)movedBytes] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    }
    else
    {
        NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bufferPtr length:(NSUInteger)movedBytes];
        NSLog(@"data is: %@", myData);
        result = [NSData base64StringFromData:myData length:myData.length];
        //  result = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Can you provide a more complete answer? I am also getting problems with this.

Answer (score 1):

Updating Waleed's Answer

key and IV could be :

```
const unsigned char *keyString = (const unsigned char *)[@"ASAF#Key$M0BiLE!WS@DG_1@"  cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
const unsigned char *initializeVactorString = (const unsigned char *)[@"ASAF@DG#" cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Complete method would be :

```
- (NSString*) EncodeText:(NSString*)plainText enc:(CCOperation)encryptOrDecrypt{

const void *vplainText;
size_t plainTextBufferSize;

if (encryptOrDecrypt == kCCDecrypt)
{
    NSString *base64EncodedString = [[plainText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    NSData *encryptData = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:base64EncodedString options:0];
    plainTextBufferSize = [encryptData length];
    vplainText = [encryptData bytes];
}
else
{
    plainTextBufferSize = [plainText length];
    vplainText = (const void *) [plainText UTF8String];
}

CCCryptorStatus ccStatus;
uint8_t *bufferPtr = NULL;
size_t bufferPtrSize = 0;
size_t movedBytes = 0;

bufferPtrSize = (plainTextBufferSize + kCCBlockSize3DES) & ~(kCCBlockSize3DES - 1);
bufferPtr = malloc( bufferPtrSize * sizeof(uint8_t));
memset((void *)bufferPtr, 0x0, bufferPtrSize);

const unsigned char *keyString = (const unsigned char *)[@"ASAF#Key$M0BiLE!WS@DG_1@"  cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
const unsigned char *initializeVactorString = (const unsigned char *)[@"ASAF@DG#" cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

uint8_t iv[kCCBlockSize3DES];
memset((void *) iv, 0x0, (size_t) sizeof(iv));

ccStatus = CCCrypt(encryptOrDecrypt,
                   kCCAlgorithm3DES,
                   kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                   keyString,
                   kCCKeySize3DES,
                   initializeVactorString,
                   vplainText,
                   plainTextBufferSize,
                   (void *)bufferPtr,
                   bufferPtrSize,
                   &movedBytes);

if (ccStatus == kCCSuccess) NSLog(@"SUCCESS");
else{
    if (ccStatus == kCCParamError) return @"PARAM ERROR";
    else if (ccStatus == kCCBufferTooSmall) return @"BUFFER TOO SMALL";
    else if (ccStatus == kCCMemoryFailure) return @"MEMORY FAILURE";
    else if (ccStatus == kCCAlignmentError) return @"ALIGNMENT";
    else if (ccStatus == kCCDecodeError) return @"DECODE ERROR";
    else if (ccStatus == kCCUnimplemented) return @"UNIMPLEMENTED";
}

NSString *result;
if (encryptOrDecrypt == kCCDecrypt)
{
    result = [ [NSString alloc] initWithData: [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bufferPtr length:(NSUInteger)movedBytes] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
else
{
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bufferPtr length:(NSUInteger)movedBytes];
    result = [myData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
}
NSLog(@"%@",result);
return result   ;
```

}

Some times server wants hex conversion, here is the way to convert string into hex

```
+ (NSString *) stringToHex:(NSString *)str{

       NSUInteger len = [str length];
       unichar *chars = malloc(len * sizeof(unichar));
       [str getCharacters:chars];

       NSMutableString *hexString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

       for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < len; i++ )
       {
          [hexString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x", chars[i]]];
       }
       free(chars);

       return hexString ;
 }

+ (NSString *) stringFromHex:(NSString *)str{

     NSMutableData *stringData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
     unsigned char whole_byte;
     char byte_chars[3] = {'\0','\0','\0'};
     int i;
     for (i=0; i < [str length] / 2; i++) {
        byte_chars[0] = [str characterAtIndex:i*2];
        byte_chars[1] = [str characterAtIndex:i*2+1];
        whole_byte = strtol(byte_chars, NULL, 16);
        [stringData appendBytes:&whole_byte length:1];
      }
      return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:stringData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
```

Comment: I found that `uint8_t iv[kCCBlockSize3DES];`  is never used, why?